# What is the song in episode 9 at 5:26?

Tags: music, fairy-tail

What is the song that starts playing at 5:26 of Fairy Tail episode 9?

Answer (score 1):

*As you haven't specified I'll assume you meant episode 9 of the first series.*

It's Fairy Tail's take on [Can Can](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Diu2N8TGKA), which is part of the [Overture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEnW5_GTooI) of [Orpheus in the Underworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orpheus_in_the_Underworld) by [Jacques Offenbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Offenbach)

You can find the whole song [here](https://youtu.be/VLTTNzkjWhs)